# How do build a subject search in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I am trying to get all the books about the author William Shakespeare in the gutemberg project (http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/gutendata/).
I can use this query in order to return all the items in which Shakespeare is the author :

```
PREFIX dc:<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf:<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?bookTitle
WHERE {
?author foaf:name "Shakespeare, William, 1564-1616".
?book dc:creator ?author;
      dc:title ?bookTitle
}
```

But I'd rather obtain the list of the criticism books about Shakespeare, using the dcterms:subjects
    http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/gutendata/resource/subject/Shakespeare_William_1564-1616.

I would really appreciate your help !

Comment: It seems like you haven't really made much effort here, assuming you actually wrote the query you posted I am suprised you couldn't change it as desired.  Replace the author name with a variable (or delete that triple entirely) and add an additional triple with `?book` as the subject with `dcterms:subjects` as the predicate and the URI you gave as the object.  If you already tried this and it didn't work then show the query that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [RobV's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304199/how-do-build-a-subject-search-in-sparql#comment25094338_17304199) that it's surprising that after writing the first query there would be much difficulty in writing the second. At any rate, the change is relatively trivial.  I checked using both `dc:subject` and `dcterms:subject`, and it appears that the Gutenberg data is stored with `dc:subject`, so I've used that in this query, not `dcterms:subject`.  This is the query; you just need to add `dc:subject <.../Shakespeare...>` to the pattern, and remove the author constraint.  A few prefixes make the query easier to write, and the results easier to read, too.

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX gp: <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/gutendata/resource/people/>
PREFIX gs: <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/gutendata/resource/subject/>
PREFIX gr: <http://wifo5-04.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/gutendata/resource/>

SELECT ?book ?author ?bookTitle WHERE {
?book dc:creator ?author ;
      dc:title ?bookTitle ;
      dc:subject gs:Shakespeare_William_1564-1616 .
}
```

With a query like this, you should end up with results like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| book          | author                                        | bookTitle                |
============================================================================================
| gr:etext14827 | gp:Guizot_François_Pierre_Guillaume_1787-1874 | "Étude sur Shakspeare"   |
| gr:etext5429  | gp:Johnson_Samuel_1709-1784                   | "Preface to Shakespeare" |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```